# Why didn't Thor show concern for His friends?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In Thor Ragnarok we see that the warriors three were slain, and Lady Sif was absent for other reasons. Being that they were close, why didn't he at least ask for them or show any concern about them; being that He wasn't present to any of the warrior's three deaths.

Comment: Im asking this because in Thor 2011, we see thier conversation about their numerous journeys and fellowship. Seeing this level of camaraderie shouldn't this be a level of concern for him. One may easily assume Hela may have dealt with them but even after her demise on the ship these are questions He could have regulated to Heimdall.

Comment: This was something that definitely bothered me about the film. It was almost like, why have the Warriors Three at all if you're going to kill them in ten seconds and have no one care about it?

Comment: The Viking way was to expect death, and revel in it as a gateway to Valhalla, not to mourn the fallen.  Viking culture was modeled after Asgard (internally, or in RL Asgard was modeled after Nordic myth).  Why would we expect Thor to mourn fallen heroes?

Comment: Because in war people die and Thor knows that

Comment: But He mourned His mother, Father, even Loki when he faked his death. Why it is true that it is expected in the Viking culture; The Viking culture does also mourn but just in a different way. To not mourn his closest friends or not even show the slightest concern was a little far fetched in my opinion.

Comment: He was busy fighting Hela, maybe that's why?

Comment: After the Miek fake-out, maybe he was too gunshy to ask about anyone else?

Answer (score 13):

### He didn't have time?

Sequence of events:

1. He arrives on Asgard after being absent for years (since the end of Thor 2: The Lost World) and identifies Loki as impersonating Odin
2. Then immediately leaves with Loki to Midgard (Earth).

   > 3. Then finds Odin (with help).
   >  4. Then encounters Hela.
   >  5. Then gets dumped on Sakaar.
   >  6. Then goes through the giant worm hole back to Asgard.
   >  7. Then immediately confronts Hela.
   >  8. Then evacuates the few survivors.
   >  9. Then Asgard is destroyed.

Probably when the dust settled and things calmed down on the ship (right before Thanos arrives) he started asking about other Asgardians, and learned of the deaths of his three companions, but he really didn't have time up until then.

Comment: You forgot "He gets a haircut by Stan Lee" :P